# What is the pack template for a sequence of floats?

Tags: perl, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have N number of floats in each line of the input text file. I'm trying to convert them into binary format (sequence of four-byte floats).

Sample line from input: `-12.391  -5.301 -12.854   0.438   8.499   4.862  -2.481   3.962`

I'm using the Perl [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) function as below

```
foreach my $line (@inputData) {
    print $outFileHandle pack('fxfxfxfx... N times', $line);
}
```

Instead of writing `fx` N times, what can I do?

Comment: I think it's a job for the repetition operator (`x`): `… pack( 'fx' x $n, $line ) …`

Comment: @larsen, thanks but that gives me this error `Argument "-10.309   0.337 -17.267   6.611   6.937   5.338  -0.870 ..." isn't numeric in pack`

Comment: Is the x is really needed in pack template (`fx`)? It just adds an extra null byte. It will return an error for sure, You need to split the line to real numbers, as dan1111 suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pack` takes a list of values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html), while you are trying to give it multiple values within a single variable.  Split on whitespace first.

Then you can use the `*` modifier to accept any number of floats:

```
pack "f*", split(' ',$line);
```

Comment: If the N is known the pack template can be `f<N>`. This is not clear if this is ta case. But You solution is correct in any case.